# how to apply code tag in the string using typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript2.0

From the api , getting the value like

```
The CSS <background-color> property defines the background color of an element.The <push> method adds one or more elements to the end of an <array> and returns the new length of the array.
```

In this string,where all I get the value between `<$string>`, I have to add code tag to that.
Here I have to apply code tag for

```
<background-color>,<push>,<array>
```

I want to add  `to the string like`

```
<code><background-color></code
<code><push></code
<code><array></code
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Use `replace` with regex:

```
const input = "The CSS <background-color> property defines the background color of an element.The <push> method adds one or more elements to the end of an <array> and returns the new length of the array.";

function addCodeTag(input: string) {
  return input.replace(/<background-color>|<push>|<array>/g, '<code>$&</code>'); 
}

addCodeTag(input);

// The CSS <code><background-color></code> property defines the background color of an element.The <code><push></code> method adds one or more elements to the end of an <code><array></code> and returns the new length of the array.
```